Need help in Response Time and Duplicate Response Issue in Node.js Slack AI Chatbot
I need assistance with my Slack AI chatbot, built on a Node.js Vercel function. The bot is experiencing an issue related to Slack event subscriptions. Specifically, the bot needs to respond to events within 3 seconds, but when handling large queries, it occasionally sends two responses. This happens because if the bot doesn't respond within 3 seconds, Slack re-triggers the event.
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { sendGPTResponse } from './_chat';

// Set to store processed request timestamps temporarily
const processedEvents: Set<string> = new Set();

async function isValidSlackRequest(request: Request, body: any) {
    const signingSecret = process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET!;
    const timestamp = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Request-Timestamp')!;
    const slackSignature = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Signature')!;
    const base = `v0:${timestamp}:${JSON.stringify(body)}`;
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingSecret).update(base).digest('hex');
    const computedSignature = `v0=${hmac}`;
    console.log('isValidSlackRequest:', { computedSignature, slackSignature });
    return computedSignature === slackSignature;
}

async function processEvent(body: any) {
    const eventType = body.event.type;
    if (eventType === 'app_mention') {
        // Process the event asynchronously with a delay
        // setTimeout(async () => {
        //   try {
        await sendGPTResponse(body.event);
        console.log(`OpenAI API call for event ${body.event_id} completed successfully.`);
        //   } catch (error) {
        //     console.error(`Error while processing event ${body.event_id} with OpenAI:`, error);
        //     // Optionally handle the error here, such as retrying or marking the event for manual intervention.
        //   }
        // }, 0); // Execute asynchronously, allowing the main thread to respond promptly
    }
}

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    console.log('Received a POST request');
    const rawBody = await request.text();
    const body = JSON.parse(rawBody);
    const requestType = body.type;
    const eventId = body.event_id;
    const response = new Response('OK', { status: 200 });

    // Check if the event is already processed
    if (processedEvents.has(eventId)) {
        console.log(`Event ${eventId} already processed. Skipping.`);
        return response;
    }

    // Mark the event as processed before actual processing to avoid race conditions
    processedEvents.add(eventId);
    console.log(`Event ${eventId} added to processedEvents set.`);

    if (requestType === 'url_verification') {
        console.log('Handling url_verification request');
        return new Response(body.challenge, { status: 200 });
    }

    if (await isValidSlackRequest(request, body)) {
        // Process the event asynchronously
        try {
            if (requestType === 'event_callback') {
                const eventType = body.event.type;

                // Filter events only for 'app_mention'
                if (eventType === 'app_mention') {
                    await processEvent(body);
                    console.log(`Event ${eventId} processing initiated.`);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error processing event ${eventId}:`, error);
        }

        return response;
    }

    console.log('Invalid Slack request');
    return new Response('Invalid request', { status: 400 });
}

// Clear processed events set every hour to prevent memory leaks
setInterval(() => {
    processedEvents.clear();
    console.log('Cleared processed events set');
}, 60 * 60 * 1000);


